# creating a array with index value dynamically in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-values

hi i want to create an array dynamically with the index value and the key value.

here $head is the array name and $values is the key value

```
$head = Array ( [0] => Dis_id [1] => Dis_Desc [2] => Dis_Per [3] => Dis_val ) 
$values = Array ([0] => Dl-Dis1  [1] => Discount [2] => 7.500 [3] => 26.25 ) 
          Array ([0] => Dl-Dis2 [1] => Discount [2] => 2.500 [3] => 73.13 )

foreach($values as $valu => $key)
       {
         $value = $value + array($head[$valu]=>$key.",");
       }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($value);
```

The output will be as

```
 Array
(
[Dis_id] => Dl-Dis2,
[Dis_Desc] => Discount,
[Dis_Per] => 2.500,
[Dis_val] => 73.13,
)
```

But the output i need is as follows

```
Array
(
[Dis_id] => Dl-Dis1,
[Dis_Desc] => Discount,
[Dis_Per] => 7.500,
[Dis_val] => 26.25,
)    
Array
(
[Dis_id] => Dl-Dis2,
[Dis_Desc] => Discount,
[Dis_Per] => 2.500,
[Dis_val] => 73.13,
)
```

i dont know how to do please help me

update to get my output

```
$values = array(array (0 => 'Dl-Dis1',  1 => 'Discount', 2 => 7.500, 3 => 26.25 ), array (0 => 'Dl-Dis2', 1 => 'Discount', 2 => 2.500, 3 => 73.13 )) ;
```

thank u all

Comment: If `$head` is your primary array and you want to use that as your index, you should iterate over `$head` and then each time foreach on `$values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use [**array_combine**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-combine.php). While under the loop, combine the `$head` and the values itself to it and put it inside a new container. Consider this example:

```
$head = Array ( 0 => 'Dis_id', 1 => 'Dis_Desc', 2 => 'Dis_Per', 3 => 'Dis_val', );
$values = array(array (0 => 'Dl-Dis1',  1 => 'Discount', 2 => 7.500, 3 => 26.25 ), array (0 => 'Dl-Dis2', 1 => 'Discount', 2 => 2.500, 3 => 73.13 )) ;

$new_values = array();
foreach($values as $value) {
    $new_values[] = array_combine($head, $value);
}
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d9Ek1Y)

Comment: thanks for your answer but my $values and your $values are change how to combine this into single array i dont know.

Comment: @rAm what do you mean by that? maybe you could post your real `$values` to avoid confusion. according to your example, `$values` is an array with also two arrays inside, isn't it?

Comment: @rAm in your example, its a multi leveled array, youre saying, there is two `$value` arrays? edit your question properly to avoid confusion and put the real codes

Comment: @rAm So its okay now? Good no problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$head = array ( 0 => 'Dis_id',  1 => 'Dis_Desc', 2 => 'Dis_Per', 3 => 'Dis_val' );
$values = array(array (0 => 'Dl-Dis1',  1 => 'Discount', 2 => '7.500', 3 => 26.25 ),
      array (0 => 'Dl-Dis2', 1 => 'Discount', 2 => 2.500, 3 => 73.13 ));
$result = array();
foreach($values as $value) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $res[$head[$key]] = $val;
    }
    $result[] = $res;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```